# ¿Cómo juntar varios datos de diferentes formularios para guardarlos en mi base de datos php?

Tags: php

actualmente tengo todo listo pero no eh podido guardar los datos, primero tengo este archivo
cual es un formulario que se llena con los datos de la persona cual finalmente es transferido a compra.php al finalizar el formulario en este archivo tomo el numero de tickets con cual calculo el valor total a pagar que finalmente al apretar al botón te redirige a la pagina de compra, donde finalmente todo es correcto y el pago es procesado te envía finalmente al archivo return.php en este caso dependiendo del valor que devuelve el proceso de pago se muestra si fue valida la compras o rechazada, ahoras todo listo necesito guardar todos los datos del formulario.php de compra.php y de return.php. Pero no tengo idea de como guardar todos estos datos en una variable de php para que cuando el token_ws me devuelva el valor de confirmación de la compra los guarde.
todos los archivos que comento están insertado abajo.

formulario.php

```html
<section class="container_form">
  <div class="form">
    <h2>Rellena el formulario para participar</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo 'compra'?>" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label for="nombres">Nombres</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombres" id="nombres" required oninput="valNombres(this)" placeholder="Nombres">
        <!--<div class="valid-feedback">Valido.</div>-->

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" required oninput="valApellidos(this)" placeholder="Apellidos">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rut">Rut</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rut" id="rut" required oninput="checkRut(this)" placeholder="11111111-1">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefono">Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="telefono" required oninput="valTelefono(this)" placeholder="985114418">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required oninput="valEmail(this)" placeholder="example@gmail.com">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reemail">Repetir Correo electrónico</label>
        <input type="reemail" class="form-control" name="reemail" id="reemail" required oninput="valReemail(this)" placeholder="example@gmail.com">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="terminos" value="ok" id="customCheck" required>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck"><a href="">Acepto los términos y condiciones de las bases del concurso.</a> </label>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="submit_compra" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-success btn-lg">PAGA AQUÍ</button>

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

compra.php

```html
<?php 
use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus\Transaction;
if (isset($_POST['submit_compra'])||isset($_POST['submit_finalizar'])){
    ?>

        <script>
            function inicio(){
                document.getElementById('sptotal').value = "$"+15000;
            };
            window.onload = inicio;
        </script>
        <section class="container_form">
            <div class="form">
                <h2>Selecciona la cantidad de ticket a comprar</h2>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Número de ticket">Número de ticket</label>
                        <select name="ticket" class="form-control" id="ticket" oninput="valTotal(this)">
                            <?php 
                                for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sptotal">Valor a pagar</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sptotal" id="sptotal" placeholder="$15.000" readonly>
                    </div>
                    
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_finalizar" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-success btn-lg">Pagar ticket</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit_finalizar'])){
        require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
        $n_tickets = (int)$_POST['ticket'];
        $total = 15000*$n_tickets;
        $amount = $total;
        $sessionId = 'sessionId';
        $buyOrder = strval(rand(10000,9999999));
        $returnUrl = 'http://localhost/frontend/return';
        $response = Transaction::create($buyOrder, $sessionId, $amount, $returnUrl);

        $formAction = $response->getUrl();
        $token_ws = $response->getToken();
        ?>
        <form method="post" name="envia" action="<?php echo $formAction ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="token_ws" value="<?php echo $token_ws ?>">
        </form>
        <script language="javaScript">
            document.envia.submit()
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}else{
    header('Location: '.$url.'formulario');
}

?>
```

return.php

```html
<?php

    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

    use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus\Transaction;
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");

    if(isset($_POST['token_ws'])){
        
        $token_ws = $_POST['token_ws'];
        $response = Transaction::commit($token_ws);
        
        if($response->getResponseCode() == 0){
            $monto = $response->getAmount();
            $hora = date("H:i");
            $fecha = date("d/m/Y");
            $cod_aut = $response->getAuthorizationCode();

            ?>
            <section class="container_vouch">
                <div class="vouch_content">
                    <div class="vouch_head">
                        <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>img/iconos/checked.png" alt="">
                        <h3>¡Tu pago fue realizado con éxito!</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vouch_body">
                        <div class="vouch_body_amount">
                            <h3>Monto:</h3>
                            <h5 class="amount">$<?php echo $monto; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vouch_body_detail">
                            <li>
                                <span>Hora:</span>
                                <span><?php echo $hora; ?></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>Fecha:</span>
                                <span><?php echo $fecha; ?></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>Cód. autorización:</span>
                                <span><?php echo $cod_aut; ?></span>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <?php

        } else {
            ?>
            <section class="container_vouch">
                <div class="vouch_content">
                    <div class="vouch_head">
                        <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>img/iconos/cancelar.png" alt="">
                        <h3>Lo sentimos. Su tansacción no se pudo llevar a cabo.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <?php
        }
    }else{
        header('Location: '.$url.'formulario');
    }


?>
```

Comment: Pasa las datos de una página a otra

Comment: lo e tenido en cuenta pero como paso los datos después que me redirecciona a la paga?, no se puede ya que todo los valores que devuelve son los que devuelve el transbank en este caso.

Comment: Podrias aclarar que es lo que quieres hacer?, cuales son las fases del pago? Como obtienes los datos?

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es guardar los datos del formulario.php los n_tickets de compra.php en mi base de datos después de que se verifique la compra, la compra se hace en compra.php donde esta es redireccionada a transbank una vez echo el pago te devuelve a return.php con el token del pago y con $response->getResponseCode() == 0 muestras que fue realizado el pago correctamente. Y lo que necesito es tener todos los datos juntos para ingresados anteriormente para guardarlos en return.php a mi base de datos yo tenia pensado crear un venta.php y utilizar clases y funciones.